Always visible app access
An elderly user accidentally ends up with an app access button (e.g. whatsapp, text messages) that hovers over all other content on the screen (camera, email, browser). These are easily removed by holding down on them and dragging them to the bottom of the screen where an x appears.
What is this feature called?
How are they creating these quick access buttons?
Can adding them be disabled?

I believe what you are referring to are called "Bubbles." Here's the Google Support Article for them.
Bubbles are usually created if a conversation is set to "Important" and a notification is received from that notification, e.g. they are created automatically.
They can be disabled system-wide in system settings:

Settings
Notifications
Bubbles
Allow apps to show bubbles -> Off

The support article I linked also shows how to turn them off if you already have a bubble on your screen:

When you notice a bubble, tap it to open it.
At the bottom left, tap Manage and then Bubbles settings.
Turn off Allow apps to show bubbles.


Yes, they are "Bubbles". Thank you, it was very difficult to research without knowing the terminology.
